# How to retrieve compound words from string list- UIMA RUTA

Tags: uima, ruta

**Sample Script:**

```
DECLARE Name,TEST;

 "Peter"->Name;
 "der Groot"->Name;
 "Robert"->Name;
 "de Leew"->Name;
 "O'Sullivan"->Name;

STRING s;
STRINGLIST slist;
Name{-> MATCHEDTEXT(s), ADD(slist,s),LOG(s)};
  ANY+ {INLIST(slist)->MARK(TEST)};
```

**Received Output:**

```
Peter
Robert
```

**Expected Output:**

```
 Peter
 der Groot
 Robert
 de Leew
 O'Sullivan
```

**Sample Input:**

```
Peter
der Groot
Robert
de Leew
O'Sullivan
```

I've tried to mark the stringlist value into an annotation type.But the received output is different from expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition at the rule element `ANY+` validates every single ANY, thus fails with the first one and also matches only single tokens.

Should the last rule annotate only position directly after `Name` annotations?

If not, the you can do something like:

```
Name{-> MATCHEDTEXT(s), ADD(slist,s)};
MARKFAST(TEST, slist);
```

If yes, the situation gets more complicated because you do not have candidates with the correct span. You cannot solve this with a combination of ANY and INLIST, You either need a correct span or fragments in the list. I'd rather recommend an additional fixing rule:

```
Name{-> MATCHEDTEXT(s), ADD(slist,s)};
MARKFAST(TEST, slist);
ANY{-ENDSWITH(Name)} @TEST{-> UNMARK(TEST)};
```

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*

Comment: Hi Peter I'm facing a new issue in this.I've edited the input file.I'm not getting "der Groot" in the TEST annotation.

Comment: Is there maybe a change of capitalization? Can you add the exemplary input?

Comment: I've added the input.